# htmlpurifier does not allow css important decleration

Tags: php, html, css, htmlpurifier

I have the following div.

```
<div align="center" style="MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt  !important; DISPLAY: block  !important; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt  !important; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt  !important"><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt  !important; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman  !important; FONT-WEIGHT: bold  !important; DISPLAY: inline  !important">UNITED STATES<font style="FONT-FAMILY: times new roman  !important; DISPLAY: inline  !important">&nbsp;</font></font></div>
```

after cleaning with htmlpurifier, !important declarations are removed. How can htmlpurifier allow it?

my config:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('CSS.Trusted', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional'); 
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [CSS.AllowImportant](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#CSS.AllowImportant)

Comment: Exactly what i want. thank you

Comment: If that fixed the problem, I'll add it as a answer, and you should mark it as completed, so others can use it in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS.AllowImportant](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#CSS.AllowImportant)